# Facebook og tags

Tags: facebook-like, meta-tags

I am using the facebook og meta tags for a like button . I read on developers.facebook.com that the og:title tag will not update after 50 likes are registered. My question is if my site's  url (in og:url) is http://abc.com/somthing.do?param1&param2... etc etc, and these params take different values, but come to the same page something.do? - will it be still considered as one page or will they be considered as 2 different urls ?

so for example 
1. http://abc.com/somthing.do?param1&param2
2. http://abc.com/somthing.do?param3&param4

Will 1 & 2 be treated as likes coming from the same page or different pages ?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the canonical url, aka. the `og:url` tag.

If a url has a different url in `og:url`, Facebook will go fetch the data again from the `og:url` url. So if `a.co?param1&param2` has og:url `a.co` then facebook will go to `a.co` to get the og tags, otherwise it won't.

You can test these things in [the debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug);